# How do I have a Horizontal ListView with pagination?

Tags: android, pagination, horizontallist

Is there such a library which does that, or a group of libraries I could merge together to implement this feature?

I've found CW's [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) and [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView), which are answers to my requirements separately.

There seem to be compatibility issues between the two. Is it possible to have these features together? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [sephiroth74's Horizontal ListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/).

For the Endless ListView, I put a `ProgressBar` in its footer. This is the code for the Endless ListView.

```
private enum ListViewStatus {
    LOADING_NEXT_PAGE, DOING_NOTHING
}

private void setEndlessListView(HListView hListView, final Data listData) {
    View footer = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.endless_list_footer, null);
    footer.setLayoutParams(new AbsHListView.LayoutParams(AbsHListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, mDimensionsFeaturedThumbnail.y));
    hListView.addFooterView(footer);

    hListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int mFirstVisibleItem;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsHListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsHListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if(visibleItemCount != 0 && firstVisibleItem > mFirstVisibleItem) {
                boolean shouldLoadMore = (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) && (mListView.getTag() == ListViewStatus.DOING_NOTHING);
                if(shouldLoadMore) {
                    loadMoreData(listData.getPageNumber()+1);
                }
            }
            mFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forget to write this line upon initializing the `ListView` and loading the data:

```
mListView.setTag(ListViewStatus.DOING_NOTHING);
```